# "Can't migrate source field body of type text_with_summary configured with plain text processing."

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to migrate a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8, but I get the following error message.

> Can't migrate source field body of type text_with_summary configured with plain text processing. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/known-issues-when-upgrading-from-drupal-6-or-7-to-drupal-8#plain-text

I read the linked documentation page and changed the body field in every content type to filtered, but the error persists.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because of 1 of 2 reasons:

1. Your text and long text fields have both plain and filtered text processing.
2. Your text with summary fields have plain text processing.

The easy way to make this go away is to set them all to filtered text during the migration.  You can do this in the hook_migrate_prepare_row() function via:

```
/**
* Implements hook_migrate_prepare_row().
*/
function YOUR_MODULE_migrate_prepare_row(Row $row, MigrateSourceInterface $source, MigrationInterface $migration) {
  // Do various tasks based on the migration id.
  switch ($migration->id()) {
    case 'upgrade_d7_field':
    case 'upgrade_d7_field_instance':
      $type = $row->getSourceProperty('type');
      switch ($type) {
        case 'text':
        case 'text_long':
        case 'text_with_summary':
        $instances = $row->getSourceProperty('instances');
        foreach ($instances as $key => $instance) {
          if (isset($instance['data'])) {
            $data = unserialize($instance['data']);
            if (isset($data['settings']['text_processing'])) {
              // Set all text processing to filtered text.
              $data['settings']['text_processing'] = 1;
              $instance['data'] = serialize($data);
              $instances[$key] = $instance;
              $row->setSourceProperty('instances', $instances);
            }
          }
        }
        break;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Also look into the class Drupal\text\Plugin\migrate\field\d7\TextField for more details as to why the migration is throwing errors.